# When enabling multilanguage on Next JS the locales folder are duplicated in the URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The issue is that when I add multilanguage to next.config.js the page "sitename.com/**lt**/hello" stoped working and opens only on "sitename.com/**lt**/**lt**/hello"

```
     module.exports = {
       i18n: {
         locales: ["en", "lt"],
         defaultLocale: "en",
         localeDetection: false,
       },
     }
```

My structure:

```
--pages
  --lt
    --hello.jsx
  index.jsx
```

I tried to delete catch and ".next" folder. Without i18n opens without the duplicate in the url....

Link to reproduction - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vercel-next-js-eao8gd?file=pages/index.tsx

Comment: I have 0 ideas whats going on =(

Comment: You don't need the `lt` folder, Next.js i18n routing handles the locale prefix automatically.